# Comparing elements in two lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have a function that compares the elements of two lists and returns the difference between them. I have two versions of it. The first one works but not the second one. What is wrong with the second function? The inputs a and b are two lists of same length.

```
def compareLists(a, b):
    A = sum([1 if i > j else 0 for i, j in zip(a, b)])
    B = sum([1 if j > i else 0 for i, j in zip(a, b)])
    return (A, B)

def compareLists(a, b):
    A = sum([1 for i in range(0, len(a)) if a[i] > b[i] else 0])
    B = sum([1 for i in range(0, len(a)) if b[i] > a[i] else 0])
    return (A, B)
```

Eg input and output: `a = [1, 2, 3,4]`; `b = [0, -2, 5, 6]`; `output = (2, 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the ternary operator (`if-else`) in the second code since using the `if` expression in a list comprehension is how the output can be filtered:

```
A = sum([1 for i in range(0, len(a)) if a[i] > b[i]])
B = sum([1 for i in range(0, len(a)) if b[i] > a[i]])
```

Adding `else` as you do in your second code makes the syntax invalid.

For completeness, as @wim noted in the comment, the use of the ternary operator is unnecessary in your first code either because Boolean values in Python are simply integers of `1` and `0`, so you can output the Boolean values returned by the comparison operators directly instead:

```
A = sum([i > j for i, j in zip(a, b)])
B = sum([j > i for i, j in zip(a, b)])
```

Comment: Correct, but might be worth mentioning that you don't need the ternary in the first code either.

Comment: Indeed. Edited for completeness. Thanks.

Comment: Oh ok. Silly mistake! May be i'll stop making those after more practice. Thank you for the answer and corrections.

Comment: You don't even need the square brackets inside `sum`